# Why does class not update ID?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I have an ID which shows an image at the top of my site

```
<div id="Introduction">
```

When I click the `<div>` it toggles the class `active` which works.

However the background image does not seem to change - can anybody tell me why?

I know the class is being added because I can see by inspecting the element.

```
#Introduction
{
    width: 95%;
    height: 280px;
    padding-top: 85px;  
    padding-left: 5%;
    background-image: url('background1.jpg');
    background-size: cover;                  
    background-position: center center; 
    transition: all 1s ease-in-out; 
 }

#Introduction .active
{
    background-image: url('background2.jpg');
}
```

Comment: your class is seperated from the id, which means it is looking for an element with the class active `IN` the #introduction element. Remove the space between it. It will check then for the active class `ON` the element #introduction

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have an error in your selector, you're checking for `.active` that is a descendant of `#Introduction`. It should be `#Introduction.active`, without a space.

Comment: Ah thank you! Its always something that is right in front of you :( Spent probably 3-4 hours trying different methods and failing to get them to work!

Answer (score 2):

Just remove the white space between `#Introduction .active`. Like `#Introduction.active`.

An space between two simple selectors `A B` is called *descendant combinator*, which would select all `B`s that are descendants of `A`s.

In this particular instance, `.active` class is added to the div having `#Introduction` ID as well, hence you should use those two selectors without any *combinators* (spaces, `>` greater-than sign, etc.).